# My app doesn't appear on iPhone 4 in notification center but on iPhone 4s it appears

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

It is very strange that the same app does appear in settings on one device and on the other not.

Can you give me an advice what to do?

Comment: Did you contact Apple? Did you find the problem? If you get the solution you should update this post with the answer, then select you answer as the correct one. Also, I see you have never selected any answer to any of your questions - you should get in the habit of doing so as you will surely then get more response to new questions.

Comment: Thanks I just reinstalled the app and now everything is ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get two support incidents each year from Apple Developer Technical Support - burn one on this. I had bizarre problem earlier this year and they helped. You can also post on their private lists which are monitored by Apple engineers.